# Fade in div after loading symbol

Tags: jquery, css, animation, loading, symbols

I am trying to load in a div after the loading symbol finishes. However It doesn't cover up the symbol while loading. Here's what I have so far:  http://jsbin.com/emofud/92/

Comment: You should accompany your questions with code as well as a link to jsbin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `div` hidden.http://jsbin.com/emofud/97

```
<div class="Reveal" style="display: none;">Hello World!</div>
```